# Loading an swf using the swfloader

Tags: apache-flex, external, swfloader

I would like to load an swf from an external domain. Is there a way i can do this using an swf loader?Currently when loading a static local swf it works but not with the external one.

Here is my swfloader which is not laoding. It looks like its getting stuck somewhere in the middle of loading.

```
<mx:SWFLoader id="mySwfLoader" width="100%" height="100%" source="https://myurl.co.za/ui/Myswf.swf"/>
```

This on the other hand works

```
<mx:SWFLoader id="mySwfLoader" width="100%" height="100%" source="path/myswf.swf"/>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Ok, sorry for that. First try adding 'http' instead of 'https' and see if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Check if the domain which you are loading to is part of the crossdomain.xml on the domain you are loading from.